# Java: Jswing: Jlist

Tags: java, swing, jlist

When i input a name to the Jlist, the name gets outputted to the lower section of the list, how do i make it to where the name is set to the top of the window

```
package Gui;

//import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI implements ActionListener {

    JButton button;
    JTextField field;
    JList list;
    JTextField name1;
    DefaultListModel listModel;
    String name;

    public GUI(){
        listModel = new DefaultListModel();
        listModel.addElement(null);
        listModel.setSize(1);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        field = new JTextField("Enter Name", 10);
        button = new JButton("Click");
        list = new JList(listModel);        

        list.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(120, 20, 20, 120));


        JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);

        panel.add(listScrollPane);
        listScrollPane.setWheelScrollingEnabled(true);

        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(field);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        button.addActionListener(this);

        }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if(arg0.getSource() == button)
            name = field.getText();
        listModel.addElement(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait... you want to change the title bar of the application???

Comment: no, when i enter in the name, i want the name to output to the top left corner of the window, but for some reason it gets sent to the bottom

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the `add(0, object)` method.

Instead of `listModel.addElement(name)`, `listModel.add(0, name)` will add the name at the top of the List.

For the size of the JList you shouldn't use this border but instead select a preferredSize for your JSCrollPane :

```
package Gui;
...    
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class GUI implements ActionListener {

    ...    
    public GUI(){
        ...
        list = new JList(listModel);

        JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        listScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 240));

        panel.add(listScrollPane);
        ...
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if(arg0.getSource() == button)
            name = field.getText();
        listModel.add(0, name);
    }
}
```

---

**Resources :**

- [JavaDoc - `DefaultListModel.add(int, Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#add%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: it made it better, but still not at the top

Comment: @Ethan, Isn't the element at the top of the list ? Or did you mean something else ?

Comment: no, like when i run this program, the name that i input gets sent to the very bottom of the window

Comment: ok, that made it still better, but when you ran this, when u enter a name, where did ur name show up? mine is sitting directly middle

Comment: Did you remove the `list.setBorder()`?